# Android linearLayout children not expanding to fill parent

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have the following as a layout of mine:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="4"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

This makes my edittext and ratingbar be pushed up to the top and both of the heights are just 'wrap_content'. I have tried with RelativeLayouts as well and all that happens is the EditText takes up the entire screen and pushes the ratingbar off the screen.

Why are the layout weights not working as expected? If edittext weight is 3 and the ratingbar is 1 I would assume the edittext would take 75% of the screen, and so forth?

The background is a 9patch image so it should have no problem expanding either.

Thank you

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have the edittext take up the top half of the screen and the ratingbar to be centered in the bottom half

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EditText"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_weight="0.53" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.53">

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change LinearLayout's

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent".
```

Also, instead of setting **"0dp"** to EditText and RatingBar set it to `match_parent`.

**[Update]**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="4"
        android:stepSize="1" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ughhhh I have no idea how I didn't notice that before, thank you! The next issue is the ratingbar is not showing up (but the view takes up the bottom half)

Comment: there is some issue with setting weight to RatingBar. See updated answer for code.

Answer (score 0):

use Relative Layout to center object:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="4"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```